# c++ read from file and match the id

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and trying to gasp the basics. I am trying to read the input of the file and print out everything in the file and most importantly, match the id of the item to the value I key in and delete the line in my file that matches with the id.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems with your code.

The first is that the input operator `>>` separates on whitespace, and not on arbitrary characters, so your parsing of the input file is wrong.

You can use e.g. [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to get the individual fields as strings, and then convert them to the correct types (either though a `std::istringstream` or by using e.g. [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)).

---

The second problem is that you read in all the data, but only saves the last line you read in. You need to store the data in a structure that is put in a vector, and then search through that vector.

Answer (score 0):

If your file format is fixed (`int`**:**`string`**:**`int`)

you can find/match "id" like following:

```
cout << "Input the id that you wish to find" << endl;
cin >> input;

char ch; // for colon (:)
while(readFile >> id >> ch >> itemName >> ch >> quantity )
{
   if (input == id) {
     //cout << "valid Input";
    }

}

readFile .close();
```